# splice not removing the element after image displayed

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

When each random image is shown, I am trying to remove it from the array. However, the splice function is not removing the random image after it has been displayed. The code looks like it should be correct based on other answers on this website.

Can anyone see why?
I can add more of the code I have if needed.

```js
function randomImageRank(){
      var images = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("images"));
      var practice = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("practice"));
    
      total = window.sessionStorage.getItem("total")
      count = total - ((JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("images")).length + JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("practice")).length) - 1);
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You are on image " + count + " of " + total;
      counter += 1


     random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
     random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
     random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
     random4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    
      var image1 = document.getElementById("drag1")
      var image2 = document.getElementById("drag2")
      var image3 = document.getElementById("drag3")
      var image4 = document.getElementById("drag4")
    
      if (practice.length > 0 ){
        image1.src = practice[0][0]
        image2.src = practice[0][1]
        image3.src = practice[0][2]
        image4.src = practice[0][3]
        practice.splice(0, 1)
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("practice", JSON.stringify(practice))
    } else {
        if (counter % 15 == 0 ) {
            image1.src = ("images/images/break_rank1.png")
            image2.src = ("images/images/break_rank2.png")
            image3.src = ("images/images/break_rank3.png")
            image4.src = ("images/images/break_rank4.png")
    } else {
        if (images.length == 0) {
            sendRank();
        } else { 
            while ((images[random1] == images[random2] ||  images[random1] == images[random3] || images[random1] == images[random4]  
                 || images[random2] == images[random4] || images[random3] == images[random2] ||images[random3] == images[random4])) {
            
                    rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
                    rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
                    rnd3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
                    rnd4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

                    random1 = rnd1
                    random2 = rnd2
                    random3 = rnd3
                    random4 = rnd4
                    console.log("duplicate")
                } 
                image1.src = images[random1]
                image2.src = images[random2]
                image3.src = images[random3]
                image4.src = images[random4]
                console.log("no duplicate")
            }
         
         counter = counter + 1
         images.splice(random1, 1);
         console.log(random1)
         images.splice(random2, 1);
         console.log(random2)
         images.splice(random3, 1);
         console.log(random3)
         images.splice(random4, 1);
         console.log(random4)
         window.sessionStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(images))

        }
      }
}
```

Comment: After each `splice` the length of the array changes and the items after the removed item are moved to a new index.

Comment: ok i understand better now! how is it possible then to remove the random images that has just been displayed without using the random variable

Comment: is it possible to remove all four randoms in the once splice? when i tried to do          images.splice(random1, random2, random3, random4, 1); it did not work